# using web fonts in fabricjs

Tags: webfonts, fabricjs

trying to use the Google Web Fonts and as per example on http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/

I am not sure what are legal values for "fontFamily" property. I tried using a random name off http://www.google.com/webfonts but it just defaults back to "Times New Roman" ("Impact" as in the examples does work though).

Where can I get a list of built-ins? (grep -R Impact * in my source tree gets 0 hits)
How can I add a custom font I want to use? (assuming it exists on google site, but also wondering about creating my own local fonts as well)

Comment: Fonts in Fabric work the same way as in HTML/CSS. As long as (remote) font file is available and _loaded_, it should render correctly. Does clicking on canvas after some time help (presumably, after font is loaded)?

Comment: ah, ok I added the css and it works now. I missed that part.

Comment: @kangax I have similar problem, and indeed clicking after some time at canvas helps. I'd like to load it from the beginning.